# How to create custom header in magento 2

Tags: magento2, header

I am looking for a Header similar to the one depicted in the below link

https://www.screencast.com/t/URbo3HmN

My default.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> <body>    <move element="navigation.sections" name="ves.topmenu" destination="header.panel" as="catalog.topnav"/>     <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true"/>      <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />      <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->     <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <move element="store_language_custom" as="store_language_custom" destination="header.panel"/>   <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>  <referenceContainer name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true"/>      <move element="form.subscribe" destination="content" />  <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <container name="footer-top" label="Footer Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="quick_bg" before="-">
              <container name="als footer-top-container" label="Als Footer Top Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container" before="-"> 

                  <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="fasony-footer">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">fasony-footer</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
              </container>
            </container>

            <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer_second">
                <container name="als-footer-container" label="Als Footer Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container" before="-">  
              </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>   <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <block class="Als\ThemeExt\Block\VesHeader" name="ves_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/ves_header.phtml"  before="-">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="menu-top" as="menutop">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">fasony-menutop</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

                <!-- TOP LINKS: settings and navigation -->
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="setting_links" as="setting_links" template="Magento_Theme::html/setting.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="currency_custom" before="store_language_custom" template="currency_custom.phtml" />
                </block>
                <!-- END TOP LINKS: settings and navigation -->
                 <block class="Als\ThemeExt\Block\HeaderInfo" name="header.info" as="header_info"/>
                 <block class="Als\ThemeExt\Block\TagLine" name="header.tagline" as="tag_line"/>

                 <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language_custom" as="store_language_custom" template="switch/languages_custom.phtml" />
            </block>
        </referenceContainer> </body> </page>
```

**ves_header.phtml**

```
<div class="text">
<?php echo "guihjhohjjo";?>
</div>
<div class="top_header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-8">
                 <ul>
                        <?php if(!$block->isLoggedIn()) {?>
                        <li class="authorization-link">

                            <?php
                            echo $block->getLayout()
                                    ->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink')
                                    ->setTemplate('Magento_Theme::account/link/register.phtml')
                                    ->setLabel('Register')
                                    ->toHtml();
                            ?>
                            <?php
                            echo $block->getLayout()
                                    ->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink')
                                    ->setTemplate('Magento_Theme::account/link/authorization.phtml')
                                    ->toHtml();
                                $dataPostParam = '';
                            ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php }?>

                              <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("customer"); ?>
                        <li>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("minicart"); ?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-8">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header_info'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clerfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="main_navigation">
    <span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Toggle Nav') ?></span></span>
    <div class="logo">
                    <h1>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("logo"); ?>
                    </h1>
                </div>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar2" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="visible-xs close-icon"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.topnav'); ?>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
        <li>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("topSearch"); ?>
          </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

What should i change as to suit my goal. can anyone help me?